# Passing data between controllers during initialization with $rootScope.$emit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a **common** module with a controller, component and template combo for initialisation purposes and defining the base layout of the app. I then have a stateful component that on initialisation makes a HTTP GET requests to fetch a background image from an API. Once the promise is resolved, I use  $rootScope.$emit to fire an event back up to the common controller with the image URL so that it can be set as the background image of the app dynamically.

What I can't get my head around is that when console logging the event response inside the $rootScope.$on() function shows me the result, but anywhere else inside in the controller yields nothing (inside $onInit() or anywhere else).

What's more baffling is that I can render the event data in the Common controller's template no problem, be it inside an input box with ng-model or inside a paragraph. When I try to concatenate it as part of my inline CSS or background-image directive however, it's not picked up whatsoever. The directive returns the URL up to the variable name (https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original) then cuts off.

Any suggestions would be really really appreciated!

This is the component controller code:

```
function MovieDetailController(MovieService, $rootScope){

    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.$onInit = function(){

    // Get all additional data
    MovieService
        .getAdditionalData(ctrl.movie.movie_id)
        .then(function(response){
            ctrl.actors = response.credits.cast.splice(0, 6);
            ctrl.extras = response.videos.results.splice(0, 3);
            ctrl.similar = response.similar.results.splice(0,6);
            ctrl.backdrop = response.backdrop_path;
            $rootScope.$emit('backdropChange', ctrl.backdrop);
        });

    }

}

angular
    .module('components.movie')
    .controller('MovieDetailController', MovieDetailController)
```

And this is the Common Controller code

```
function CommonController($state, $rootScope){

    var ctrl = this;

    $rootScope.$on('backdropChange', function(event, data){
        ctrl.backdrop = data;
        // Displays result successfully
        console.log('Back drop is ' + ctrl.backdrop);
    });

    ctrl.$onInit = function(){
        // Doesn't log result
        console.log('On Init, Backdrop is ' + ctrl.backdrop);
    }
}

angular
    .module('common')
    .controller('CommonController', CommonController);
```

Here is the HTML template for the Common Controller

```
<header class="row" id="topnav">
    <topnav class="col-sm-12 p-3 d-inline-flex"></topnav>
</header>

<!-- Testing if data is rendered inside the input box and it is! -->
<div class="col-sm-12"><input type="text" name="" ng-model="$ctrl.backdrop"></div>

<!-- Directive only receives first part of URL up to variable then cuts off-->
<main class="row" id="main-body" back-img="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original{{$ctrl.backdrop}}">
    <aside class="flex-fixed-width-item bg-white" id="sidebar">
        <sidebar></sidebar>
    </aside>
    <section class="col" id="content-window">
        <!-- Filters and Main Section Submenu -->
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="col-sm-12 filter-container">
                <div ui-view="details-menu"></div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- Main Content Section -->
        <div ui-view="details" class=""></div>
    </section>
</main>
```

Last but not least the background image directive

```
function backImg(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var url = attrs.backImg;
            element.css({
                'background-image': 'url(' + url +')'
            });
        }
    }
}

angular
    .module('common')
    .directive('backImg', backImg);
```

[image: Logs and data rendering of problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `backImg` directive should `$observe` the attribute:

```
function backImg(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            attrs.$observe("backImg", function(url) {
                element.css({
                    'background-image': 'url(' + url +')'
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

From the Docs:

> ## $observe(key, fn);
>
> Observes an interpolated attribute.
>
> The observer function will be invoked once during the next `$digest` following compilation. The observer is then invoked whenever the interpolated value changes.
>
> [— AngularJS Attributes API Reference - $observe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe)

Comment: Fantastic! That got the image through and everything is working fine! :D I had a look through the docs but I have another question: Why is it that I was successful in interpolating the data directly in the html inside a <p> tag but I needed $observe for the directive? Also, the console still shows a 404 error for the image url (clipping it right before the interpolation) even though the image has loaded successfully. It'd really help me out if you could explain this a bit better ^^. Thank you once again!